# Squid bind each outgoing ip to a user?

Tags: authentication, proxy, acl, squid

I am trying to use squid and bind 2 outgoing ips separately to 2 users.

The ideal results will be, I can access the following:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.14:3128:user1:user1password 
xxx.xxx.xxx.18:3128:user2:user2password
```

But not:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.14:3128:user2:user2password 
xxx.xxx.xxx.18:3128:user1:user1password
```

I find a similar question and use a similar squid.conf:

[squid bind outgoing ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53595197/squid-bind-outgoing-ip)

Here is my config:

```
acl http proto http
acl port_80 port 80
acl port_443 port 443
acl CONNECT method CONNECT


auth_param basic program /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwords
acl ncsa_users proxy_auth REQUIRED
external_acl_type userIp %SRC %LOGIN /usr/lib64/squid/ext_file_userip_acl -f /etc/squid/userIp.conf

acl userIp external userIp

http_access deny !ncsa_users
http_access allow userIp
http_access deny all

http_port 3128
acl ip1 myip xxx.xxx.xxx.14
tcp_outgoing_address xxx.xxx.xxx.14 ip1

acl ip2 myip xxx.xxx.xxx.18
tcp_outgoing_address xxx.xxx.xxx.18 ip2
```

And in my userIp.conf I have:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.14 user1
xxx.xxx.xxx.18 user2
```

And in my /etc/squid/passwords I have the following created by htpasswd:

```
user1:encrypted password
user2:encrypted password
```

The problem is:
if I delete **'http_access deny !ncsa_users'**, then user1 can access both xxx.xxx.xxx.14 and xxx.xxx.xxx.18. Same with user2.

But if I keep **'http_access deny !ncsa_users'** as it is, then all connection fails.

I feel **'http_access allow userIp'** doesn't work as it intends to.

I can't search a similar problem on web... Hope anyone could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I figured out now.

%SRC %LOGIN pair means specify the user's own pc addresses' source, which is actually not what I want.

What I want is actually %MYADDR %LOGIN pair, which specify the ips to allow each user connect to.

So yea, that's the problem